# ODBC connection in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

In Windows Server 2008 R2 not showing Microsoft ODBC for Oracle 64 bit.

I made a connection string. Go to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe` and add username and server and select Microsoft Odbc for Oracle but When I run my application it shows:

> ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not
>   found and no default driver specified

My connection string is following:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="conct" connectionString="DSN=mydb;UID=123;PWD=334"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

How I remove this error and How I check which one wrong my connection string or driver not found?

Answer (score 3):

`C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe` is used for accessing 32-bit ODBC drivers on Windows x64. If your desired driver is 64-bit, you need to use `c:\windows\system32\odbcad32.exe`.

Comment: but c:\windows\system32\odbcad32.exe not showing Microsodt ODBC for oracle

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread your question. You are correct, there is no 64-bit version of the Microsoft Oracle driver; it is deprecated (see here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/15/system-data-oracleclient-update.aspx). You'll need to use Oracle's ODBC or some other driver if you need 64-bit support.